# ibm bpm - execute sql statement return type

Tags: ibm-bpm

how to manage the result of a query that returns an integer "`select count(*) from table`"?

1) I've tried to bind the output of a `SQL Execute Statement` service to an integer variable and doesn't work. (type mistmatch)

2) i've tried to use types like `'SQLResult', SQLResultRow, SQLResultColumn`  as well but they dont work:

> Caused by: com.lombardisoftware.core.TeamWorksException: Type ismatch the value "[Element: ]" must be and instance of type atructured IBM BPM Java Class found: org.jdom.Element

3) i've tried to bind the output  to a XMLElement variable and i've got this value

> < resultSet recordCount=\"1\" columnCount=\"1\">5< /columnn>< /record>< /resultSet>

so now... how can I access the recordCount attribute of this node?

anyway, I don't like so manipulate a variable of XMLType, when are the types `SQLResult, SQLResultRow, SQLResultColumn` used?

> ****** EDITED *******

even if i get a result as XMLElement..  i can't manipulate it.

methods like: `tw.local.result[0].rows[0].column[0].getText()`  don't work (the intellisense as well)
the **XMLElement** as an attribute **"recordCount"** but i don't know how to get his value..

Anyway, the only workaround that i found is to change the query in order to return a normal set of records(not a scalar value)
`select field from table`  instead of `select count(field) from table`
so i could to map the output value to a list of objects and than count its `length`...

ugly and dirty :-(

anyone know how manipulate the XMLElement in a script block?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

Bind the output variable from sql execute statement as 'ANY' type.

**variable name** - result (ANY)

**Query** - select count(field) as COUNTVAL from table

tw.local.totalCount = tw.local.result[0].rows[0].indexedMap.COUNTVAL;

Comment: `'Variable type was not a complex type: ANY'.`

**INPUT BINDINGS**
`sql = "select count(codice) as conteggio from prodotti", 
returnType= "ANY", 
dataSounrceName = "jdbc/Mysourcename"` (works, tested with others queries), 

**OUTPUT BINDINGS**
`tw.local.result (ANY).`


i've tried to remove `"returnType"` as well but in this case, there is no exception but neither the result

Comment: Sorry my syntax was wrong. Try below. In case you are using tw.local.result ( ANY ). Then you can set returnType = null in Input Bindings.
tw.local.totalCount = tw.local.result[0].rows[0].indexedMap.COUNTVAL;

Comment: Thanks it works! please, editi the original post so i'll mark it a s resolved! thanks a lot. *PS: do you have any docs about how the return types are automatically mapped and how to know more? the ibm docs sucks!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Use **Return type as XMLElement** then bind a XMLElement in output mapping.

For eg: If you are using **tw.local.output** as ouput mapping (of type XMLElement) then,

```
log.info("Count "+tw.local.output.xpath('/resultSet/record/column').item(0).getText());
```

This will print the  count
If you want to get **"recordCount"** Attribute then use

```
tw.local.output.getAttribute("recordCount");
```